# How do I implement Extent Reports in my REST assured API testing framework?

Tags: automated-testing, test-automation-framework, api-testing, test-report, testing-framework

I have recently started rest assured to automate APIs. My current framework folder structure has an ApiTestCases class in a folder under src/test/java.
I have a testNG suite xml to run the tests. How do I implement extent reports with this structure? I have tried to look online but its confusing. Please tell step by step detailed instructions. Also, do I need to create a Utility folder under src/test/java?

Please help me get started with this! Thus far I have added the extent report dependency version 3.0 in my POM.xml

Comment: Why not use Allure?

Comment: Hello Rohan, have you tried this link? https://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/generate-extent-reports/

Answer (score 0):

The below sample script worked for me in creating Extent reports and make changes according to your testcases for rest assured api framework.

```
//For creating html

    ExtentReports extent = new ExtentReports("./report/result.html",false);

//For creating each test
ExtentTest test = extent.startTest("Your testcase name","short description of your testcase");

test.assignCategory("Type of testing");//For example Smoke or sanity or regression

test.assignAuthor("Name of the author");//Author name who created the testcase

//For testcase status along with description
test.log(LogStatus.PASS,"The value entered successfully");

extent.endTest(test);
extent.flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have testbase in your project you can implement extent report basic methods in that class like below

[image]

Then call that method in your test class